# Searching mySQL for Data and Cross referencing

Tags: php, mysql

So Iam not sure how to explain what I am looking for but will explain the best I can.

I have a mySQL database with the following Column Names `|Name1|Name2|Name3`these are the Column names. Under each Column there is a name`|Mark Abc|Jim Abc|Kim Abc`. Ok that is part 1, next I have another Table with the following Columns `|Name|Weeknum|`so when i update this table it would have some data like `|Mark Abc|Week-03|`.

So the question I have is how do i create a PHP script that will take the value from under Name1 and search for that name under name and weeknum and return a value like this-`Week-01 Week-02 Completed Week-04`.

So basically will list all the 52 Weeks and if any are found to match `Name|Weeknum` then it would list `Completed`, thanks in advance

Comment: [Inner join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)?

Comment: `SELECT Weeknum FROM Table2 WHERE Name=?` - Is that what you mean?

Comment: I would like to search all weeknum and list all week numbers and so there would be `Week-01 to Week-52` and any Weeknum that are found matching `Name` then would change that Weeknum into Completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer if you could add a field called id and make it primary for the first table and create another field in the second table with the same name ( ID ) and it will be foreign key then is easy to do what you were asking for , cause every name has its own id .

```
    Table 1

    ID    NAME  
    1     Mark Abc
    2     Jim Abc
    3     Kim Abc

    Table 2

    ID  Weeknum
    1   Week-03
    1   complete
    3   Week-09
```

Now lets assume that i wanted to execute this query :

```
" SELECT Weeknum FROM TABLE 2 WHERE id = 1; "
```

This will give us this output :

```
Weeknum
Week-03
complete
```

What happened is Mark Abc has the id = 1 and we searched for his id Table 2 .

If you did what i suggest this Query will do the job

i will assume that you are already linked your database and i will just give you the query : i will use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) to type the query :

```
$FetchInfo = $conn>prepare("SELECT Weeknum FROM TABLE 2 WHERE id = 1");
$FetchInfo->execute();

While($FI = $FetchInfo->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   echo $FI['weeknum']."\n";
  }
```

Now if you don't want to use what i suggest you can easily do this :

```
    $FetchInfo = $conn>prepare("SELECT Weeknum FROM TABLE 2 WHERE NAME = Mark Abc ");
    $FetchInfo->execute();

    While($FI = $FetchInfo->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
       echo $FI['weeknum']."\n";
      }
```

Tow Notes :

- I used PDO to type and execute the query , if you don't know what is it let me know so i can edit the answer and replace my PDO code to Mysqli code .
- Just for the future when you want to type query don't do this:

`$FetchInfo = $conn>prepare("SELECT Weeknum FROM TABLE 2 WHERE id = 1");
 $FetchInfo->execute();`

Its so danger , and it could be opened for SQL INJECTION . What is that and how to fix that?

Whats is it :

> SQL injection is a code injection technique, used to attack
>   data-driven applications, in which nefarious SQL statements are
>   inserted into an entry field for execution (e.g. to dump the database
>   contents to the attacker).

How to fix it in the example in this answer is by doing this :

```
$FetchInfo = $conn>prepare("SELECT Weeknum FROM TABLE 2 WHERE id = ?");
$FetchInfo->execute(array(1));
```

Read this too : [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Hope this help you .

Comment: thanks for the info, I will try to adapt my code to yours, thanks

Comment: @INOH yea no problem , please if you need help , just let us know =

Answer (score 1):

What I gather from the comments is that you mean something along the lines off

```
Update Table2
Set Weeknum='Completed'
Where Name='Mark Abc'
```

I hope this is what you mean